# Validating input type number in html5

Tags: validation, html, input

I want to restrict entry of input onto a field of type number such that input cannot be outside range of min-max specified in the html.

```
input type = "number" min = "1" max = "5"
```

Is there a way of outputting the number field without the text box and i would rather not use

`"input type = range"`

as slider does not show value currently selected

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: The spinbox control of HTML5 doesn't provide restrictions on input values of you input values directly through number keys, the range will be taken care of only when spin buttons are pressed, instead, you should make restrictions using JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you said, I suggest using a simple input text field and check it's value validity on submission via JavaScript (as @Kush mentions above). You could also check it as the user types, or moves focus away from that field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
  Only 1 to 100 <input type="text" name="number" pattern="\d{1,2}(?!\d)|100" title="one to hundreed only">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```